# String from document meets value of array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor

I've got an array of Project ID's, for example:
`[ 'ExneN3NdwmGPgRj5o', 'hXoRA7moQhqjwtaiY' ]`

And in my Questions collection, I've got a field called 'project', which has a string of a project Id. For example:

```
{
    "_id" : "XPRbFupkJPmrmvcin",
    "question" : "Vraag 13",
    "answer" : "photo",
    "project" : "ExneN3NdwmGPgRj5o",
    "datetime_from" : ISODate("2017-01-10T08:01:00Z"),
    "datetime_till" : ISODate("2017-01-10T19:00:00Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-01-10T08:41:39.950Z"),
    "notificationSent" : true
}
{
    "_id" : "EdFH6bo2xBPht5kYW",
    "question" : "sdfadsfasdf",
    "answer" : "text",
    "project" : "hXoRA7moQhqjwtaiY",
    "datetime_from" : ISODate("2017-01-11T11:00:00Z"),
    "datetime_till" : ISODate("2017-01-11T17:00:00Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-01-10T10:21:42.147Z"),
    "notificationSent" : false
}
```

Now I want to `return` all documents of the Questions collection, where the Project (id) is one of the value's from the Array.

To test if it's working, I'm first trying to return one document.
Im console.logging like this:

`Questions.findOne({project: { $eq: projectArray }})['_id'];`
but have also tryed this:
`Questions.findOne({project: { $in: [projectArray] }})['_id'];`

But keep getting 'undefined'

Comment: replace `findeOne` to just `find` and changed `$in` as `{project: { $in: projectArray}}`

Comment: Lol the brackets --> [] were the problem.. Feel so stupid.. Thnks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
Questions.find({project: { $in: projectArray }}) => for fetching all docs with those ids
Questions.findOne({project: { $in: projectArray }}) => if you want just one doc
```